# Microsoft SQL Server - Operating System Error 32

Tags: sql-server

So basically what I am trying to do, is attach a database in Microsoft SQL Server, but I keep getting the following error:

[SQL Server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qRnG.png)

I even downloaded Process Explorer in order to find if the .mdf file that I am trying to import is being used by another process, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to attach the master database?

Comment: I am actually trying to import the master database from another schema, which is also called master and when I attach it I change the name, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: Import master from another schema? That doesn't make any sense at all. The master database is a system database.

Comment: What I am getting at is that when your instance is running there is a master database already so you can't just attach a new copy of it. What is in this master that you want? You should script out those objects and run it.

Comment: @SeanLange How can I do that? SSMS won't let me open that file, editing with notepad++ gives characters with no meaning.

Comment: You would script whatever objects you need from the instance where they are currently.